# How to resurrect old feature in same git branch?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I'd like to think that my problem is potentially rather common and it ought to have well-known solution or best-practice.
Unfortunately every solution I've found and/or tried present some kind of undesired side effect.

My repo basically looks like the following, even though in my real repo there are 25 or so commits between E and G and some other branches sticking out on the sides:

```
A--B------E--F--G   <-- master
    \    /
     C--D           <-- branch_1
```

Branch_1 contains an implementation proposal for a feature that exists in commit B, but was implemented differently. It was decided that the implementation proposal in branch_1 should be the official one and hence branch_1 was merged to master.
Since the merging of branch_1 several bug fixes have been made in commits F and G, some related to the feature and others not so related.
It turns out that the implementation proposal from branch_1 was not so great after all, so I need to bring the implementation in commit B to a new commit at the tip of master. I also want it to be clear that commit B is a contributor to the new commit, e.g. when I issue `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`. What I want is something like this:

```
     -------------H <-- branch_2
    /            /
A--B------E--F--G   <-- master
    \    /
     C--D           <-- branch_1
```

**TLDR;** How can I create branch_2 and merge commit G into it excluding changes introduced by branch_1 in commit E?

Read on for what I've tried so far...

The first thing I tried was to checkout B, create a new branch 'branch_2' and merge master into branch_2. What happened was that git concluded that fast-forward was in order since all subsequent commits are newer, so I ended up with a branch_2 which was identical to master and thus losing what I needed from commit B. Of course `--no-ff` gives the same result for the same reason.
I have tried various merge strategies and they all create the same result apart from `ours`. I expect to manually merge bits and pieces, but I would like to minimise that labour if possible. I have tried to find a way to make git create merge conflicts, but I always end up with a code base identical to either master or commit B without any conflicts.

Since merging this way doesn't seem to solve my problem I thought I would give cherry-picking a go. So I reset my branch_2 with `git reset --hard B` and tried `git cherry-pick F --no-commit` since commit E is only a merge commit. 
The resulting code base contained one merge conflict that was easily solved. But as I solved the conflict I realised that I missed out on more than 80% of the code changes in F that I need. I tried cherry-picking from E instead and git told me to use `-m`, but depending on whether I use '1' or '2' as mainline, I end up in a problem similar to when merging above; the resulting code base is either identical to B or E.

At this point I took a considerable detour involving `git diff`, `interdiff` and `rediff/recountdiff` to try and create patches with the differences between B and G compared to differences between E and G. I guess it is possible, but I still haven't figured out how to accomplish what I'm after. On the other hand I would like to think that git should be able to help me with this.

To me the above is a major part of the purpose of using a version control system/software; I can go back in my development history and resurrect pieces of code that I need.
I'm certain that this is about my git skills being limited, I've only been using git for half-a-year. Perhaps there is a concept in git that has eluded me or a term that I'm currently unfamiliar with since I'm not able to find the correct answer for my problem in my searches.
I know how to accomplish the above in ClearCase, but that doesn't help... ;-)

Comment: Are the commits in E..G well separated? i.e. Does each commit only deal with a bug-fix to something from `branch_1` or something not from `branch_1`? If so, your best bet may be to `git checkout -b branch_2 B`, and then `git cherry-pick <list of commits from E-G that didn't affect branch_1 stuff>`. You can still do it if some of the commits had mixed content, but it'll be a bit more messy and manual...

Comment: @twalberg Unfortunately the commits E..G are not well separated. Some of them contains changes related to `branch_1` and some not. I realise that cherry-picking is technically an option, but according to my "limited" git skills it becomes impractical when the problem is scaled up and there may be hundred commits between E and G. That is why I am looking for another solution.

Comment: Does `git checkout G; git revert `B..E` produce the content you want?

Comment: "merging this way doesn't seem to solve my problem" -- right.  Merge combines the accumulated changes in each commit since their last common ancestor, for B and G that's B, only G has made changes since.

Answer (score 1):

One easier solution would be to revert `E` ([`git revert`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert))

```
git checkout master
git checkout -b branch_2
git revert -m 1 <SHA1 of commit E>
```

That would cancel any modification introduced by `E`, creating a new commit `H` which will be the negative image of `E`.
`F` and `G` would still be part of that new history.

```
                  H <-- branch_2
                 /
A--B------E--F--G   <-- master
    \    /
     C--D           <-- branch_1
```

Comment: I'm not sure reverting the merge commit E (which probably only introduced minimal conflict-resolution changes) will fully accomplish what is desired - it might require reverting C and D (and any other commits on `branch_1`.

Comment: @twalberg strange... I believe E should be enough

Comment: Interesting, even though it's not very clear that B is a contributor to H. I haven't understood that it was possible to revert an explicit commit further back in history and still keep subsequent commits. I will try it out in different ways. Got some new ideas based on your answer. I will post again and let you know how it goes.

Comment: @VonC `git revert` reverts the changes introduced by a specific commit, not the changes introduced by commits earlier on that branch. Since E introduced no changes other than conflict resolution ones, those would be the ones to be reverted. If you want to revert the changes introduced by commit C, you need to `git revert C`...

Comment: [This is in the manpage:](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html) `git revert -m1` says branch 1 is the mainline, all changes introduced from other branches are to be reverted.  That page links to [Linus giving How To Revert a Faulty Merge lessons](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/howto/revert-a-faulty-merge.txt)

Answer (score 1):

### General

> ... try and create patches with the differences between B and G
> compared to differences between E and G. I guess it is possible, but I
> still haven't figured out how to accomplish what I'm after. On the
> other hand I would like to think that git should be able to help me
> with this.

In this situation I would resort to using `git rebase --onto` with explicit version arguments. What you want is a new branch based on `B` with the changes in `F` and `G` added, right? This can be done with

```
$ git branch branch_2 master     # Point branch_2 to the latest change to include
$ git rebase --onto B E branch_2        # Take changes from E (not including)
                                        # to (including) G and put on top of B
```

That should give you something like

```
     --F'--G'       <-- branch_2
    /            
A--B------E--F--G   <-- master
    \    /
     C--D           <-- branch_1
```

Where the `F'` and `G'` commits are the changes in F and G relative to B.

### Splitting of commits

> Since the merging of branch_1 several bug fixes have been made in
> commits F and G, some related to the feature and others not so
> related.

Because of this I would try to split up the commits in two parts, one with branch_1 related changes and one for the rest.

```
$ git branch branch_2 master
$ git rebase -i E
...
# Select `edit` for all versions and exit the editor
...
```

Git will now take you back to the first version, F. To split a commit I do the following: reset/remove the commit stored in the git data base but not undo/remove any content in the existing files with the command

```
$ git reset HEAD^
```

Now all changes done in F will be still present but as uncommited changes (you can check with `git status`). Now you want to commit the changes again, but in two (or more) steps. Run

```
$ git add -p
...
# Add only those parts related to branch_1
...
$ git diff --cached       # Should show only changes related to branch_1
$ git diff                # Should show the other changes
```

Also check (with `git status`) if there are any untracked files that should be added with `git add`. When satisfied run

```
$ git commit -m "commit F1"           # Possibly some other commit message...
$ git add <all_the_remaining_files>
$ git commit -m "commit F2"
$ git rebase --continue
```

Git will now stop on version G, repeat the above correspondingly.

All of the above "split commit operation" will not introduce any merge conflicts and is 100% safe to do (and in a way have changed nothing...), but now it hopefully should be simpler to include/exclude the things you want.

You should now have

```
            --F1--F2--G1--G2       <-- branch_2
           /            
A--B------E--F--G                  <-- master
    \    /
     C--D                          <-- branch_1
```

### Exclude/include

At this point you could just do

```
$ git checkout -b branch_2 B
$ git cherry-pick F2
$ git cherry-pick G2
```

and if no conflicts occur, you are done. But in case of conflicts git does not have any support for using mergetool when cherry-pick fails, so things are a bit cumbersome to recover from<sup>1</sup>, so the following is a better way.

```
$ git checkout -b branch_2 master
$ git rebase -i E
...
# Remove the F1 and G1 commits
...
```

This might result in conflicts just as cherry-pick would, but I think `git mergetool` will work in this case (I always use my own script...). With no conflicts or conflicts resolved, continue with

```
$ git rebase --onto B E branch_2
```

You should now have

```
     --F2--G2       <-- branch_2
    /            
A--B------E--F--G   <-- master
    \    /
     C--D           <-- branch_1
```

---

<sup>1</sup>I have my own "git add -p" like script which parses `git ls-files -u` and fetches versions with `git cat-file` and feeds them to kdiff3. Update: the script is now published on github: https://github.com/hlovdal/git-resolve-conflict-using-kdiff3

Comment: I think you meant the first 'general' section as informative, right?
The following sections I am not sure since both start with creating the same branch, but from different commits. I guess I'm supposed to split the commits before cherry-picking.
The downside is that when doing so it seems necessary to "edit" each one of the +20 subsequent commits that follow `E`, which suggests to me that this way is somewhat impractical. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: @Roger Yes, the general part is a "paralell" introduction track, you should start on the split section.

Comment: Although perhaps ideally all commits should be split up, this is not mandatory. You can if you will go ahead with no splits. That will almost certainly result in some merge conflitcs, but it might be simple enought to handle so that this is less work than spliting first and then exclude commits. There is not a an all or nothing criteria for splitting, you migh very well split only some. So you can try first with no splits, and then if some conflicts turns out to be difficult, you can split only those corresponding commits.